# in flask-WTF forms how to custom the size of text field?

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

In forms created by flask-wtf, how can I specify the height and width of text field input

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %} Title {% endblock %}
{% block body %}
 <form method="POST">
     {{ form.textfld.label }} <br>
     {{form.textfld(size=100)}}
 </form>
{% endblock %}
```

This is the only example I can find which changes only the width but not height. I tried to add a class to it and target the class in base.html but nothing is changed.

Comment: Try to set cols and rows: Ex) {{ form.text(cols="35", rows="100") }}

Comment: I tried that as I saw it in other answers to similar question. Strangely it didn't change anything.

Comment: Even adding CSS won't work as well?

Comment: I tried wrap  {{form.textfld(size=100)}} in a div and format the div in a css referenced in base.html but it didn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you add a `render_kw` dict to the form specification:

```
class Form(Form):
     field = SomeField(*args, render_kw=dict(class='my_class'))
```

then in the HTML the text `class="my_class"` will be automatically rendered for the field, so you customise the properties via the CSS class.